# Incorporating z buffer information into shading

Tags: vtk

I want to be able to darken (or lighten) objects farther away from the camera to provide some depth perception in my scene. I've looked into the [ZBuffer](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/ZBuffer) example but this seems to only export an image of the z buffer (while simultaneously losing the color information), whereas I am looking to do something similar to this in real-time and retaining color in the scene.

Basically, how could I incorporate Z buffer information into the shading/coloring of the scene?

Answer (score 0):

This [blog article](https://blog.kitware.com/eye-dome-lighting-a-non-photorealistic-shading-technique/) explains a shading method using the depth buffer called the Eye-Dome Lighting and also have an implementation in ParaView as an optional RenderView plugin. I think the idea is based on the use of the `vtkDepthImageProcessingPass` class.